# Need help understanding 心は気高く / そのまた先で感じていくの

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

From [this song](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/seireitsukai/bladedance.jis):

> 宙よりも高く 宙よりも高く
>   どこまでも駆け昇っていくの
>   心は気高く 心は気高く
>   **そのまた先で感じていくの**
>   あの日描いた未来を わたしたちの理想論を
>   実現(させる) 踊る刃(やいば)達の祭壇へ

Can anyone explain how the line “そのまた先で感じていくの” relates to the rest?

My rough translation:

> *Higher than the sky, Higher than the sky
>
>   We will keep ascending to new heights*
>   **???**
>   *To make the future we dreamed of that day into reality
>
>   To realise our vision of an ideal world
>
>   We head to the altar of dancing blades*

The two lines that I'm not sure of is how to express 心は気高く in English and what it means by そのまた先で感じていくの.

Comment: Can you explain how much of this you understand?

Comment: IF you're asking for some rough translation that is not literal:
.....
Higher than the sky, Higher than the sky 
We will keep ascending to new heights



To make the future we dreamed of that day into reality
To realise our vision of an ideal world
We head to the altar of dancing blades

edit:posting like this ruins the formatting but hopefully you understand. The two lines that I'm not sure of is how to express 心は気高く  in english and what it means by そのまた先で感じていくの.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is that you don't realize that また can be inserted into その先, like

> その先の、その先の、その **また** 先 (のそのまたうーんと先)
>   Further than that, further than *that* and further than that **again** (and even further than *that*)

The lines just before have

> 心は気高く 心は気高く

So, *beyond* that place where "our hearts are sublime", we'll (actually) "be experiencing that day, when we painted our future".

(Note that the part あの日描いた未来を would in a standard sentence come before そのまた先で感じていく, like あの日描いた未来をその先で感じていく.)

I'm really bad at translations, but the grammar involving また is straight-forward, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are looking for the *object* of the verb "感じる", because you're interested in the relationship of this line and the rest of the lyrics.

There are three verbs ("感じる", "実現させる", "踊る") and two nouns with direct object marker `を` ("未来を", "理想論を") in the last three lines. When I *read* these lines, the grammatical relationship of these words was not very clear to me (and I'm a native Japanese speaker).

1. "未来を感じていく" & "理想論を感じていく" & "実現する (w/o specific object)" ?
2. "未来を感じていく" & "理想論を実現する" ?
3. "感じていく (w/o specific object)" & "未来を実現する" & "理想論を実現する" ?

So I had to [listen to the song directly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4H9Wvli2fY). And the way of singing revealed that the first two interpretations are *very* unlikely. It sounded like "そのまた先で感じていくの" does not strongly relate to the subsequent lines, and the object of 感じていく was not really specified anywhere.

As a result, "We'll keep on feeling, at somewhere even further than that" is all that's explicitly written in the line. I'm not sure, but perhaps "(熱い)想い" or some kind of fighting spirit which is sung all over the lyrics, is the implicit target of 感じる here.